# Remote desktop access between two Windows machines via USB

Tags: windows, usb, remote-desktop, desktop, remote

Is there a way to connect two Windows machines via USB cable so they can access each other via a remote desktop application (freeware) or even the default Windows RDP client?

I can't use a network connection because I'm not allowed to. If it is possible: Is USB 2.0 fast enough to transfer a responsive feeling? I don't want to transfer files.

Comment: It would definitely be easier (and perfectly safe) to directly connect the machines via Ethernet. You might need a crossover cable though, depending on how new the NICs are.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not allowed to use Ethernet or any connection at all? You can get two USB network cards and connect each other. (or pair USB to Ethernet converters as cheaper way)

If you can't use any network, then all what comes to my mind is KVM.

Comment: The problem is, that one PC is connected to our business network. If Ethernet is the only way: Is there a way that I can completely encapsulate the PC-to-PC-network from the business network? My boss told me it's okay if the business network is not able to detect the other network.